# Can't open index.php file from Mobile browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, web

I have a web application. It's back-end is in PHP. There are some directories inside the application. Some of the directory has index.php file. The Problem is when I am trying to route users to other .html pages in the same directory it's working fine. Now one of the directory has index.php file and in the link I have given the relative path to the folder (So by default it is loading index.php file in that directory from Desktop,Labtop etc) but it is not loading that page when I try to run the same from any mobile browser. After Inspection I realized that I can see **somefolder/index.php** in the address bar while in mobile it is just till the **somefolder** i.e it is not trying to load index.php file due to which I get **"Not Found"** 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `DirectoryIndex` correctly. When calling the directory from an web accessible URL without any file name, it tries to access your `DirectoryIndex` file, per default it is called `index.php`, `index.html`, `index.htm`, `index.cgi` etc.. This depends also on your platform. Different systems have different default `DirectoryIndex` configurations. If those index file does not exist, you should see the directory listing in the web browser, even if the web server user has the rights to list the content of the current directory (special bit under Linux/UNIX and maybe protected by advanced kernel security applications like selinux or AppArmor).

What happens, if you try to access the folder directly without any file name from an desktop browser? Will you get there the HTML output of index.php?

Comment: Yeah that's what it's happening now. I just have a link to the folder not the actual file in the link tag and it's loading by default index.php file from desktop browser but not from mobile browser.

Comment: without knowing the content of index.php it is impossible to say why it fails on mobile clients. Please post us your code. Because I think it must be an error in your php file, that searches the user agent header for mobile clients or something like that. Also post us the full network response from your browser's developer tools under the network tab for the URL request (HTTP Status Code and response body).

Comment: I will do that in a while.